# Betamax is not recording calls to RESTClient in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, spock, betamax

I have a Betamax test that I'm trying to configure to intercept calls to a web service that is using RESTClient. The calls to the web service aren't getting recorded. My test code looks like this:

```
@Betamax(tape = 'pending_transfer_success')
        void "test createPendingTransfer"() {
            BetamaxRoutePlanner.configure(restClient.client)
            BetamaxHttpsSupport.configure(restClient.client)

            when:
            Transfer transfer = service.createPendingTransfer(
                    beneficiaryFirstName, beneficiaryLastName, beneficiaryUserEmail, lineItemsIdsToTransfer)

            then:
            ...
    }
```

Inside the setup() method I'm configuring the RESTClient like so:

```
restClient = new RESTClient("${grailsApplication.config.acme.account.api.url}/")
service.restClient = restClient
```

The app is a Grails 2.2.3 app and the test is written using Spock. Any help explaining why the calls isn't being recorded would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Betamax version are you using? Do you have other tests that are recording successfully or is this the first one you've tried? Is this a unit or integration test?

Comment: Betamax version is 1.1.2. We have another test that is using Betamax but it's not a Spock test (it extends GroovyTestCase). This test is a Spock unit test.

Comment: Hmm, Spock shouldn't be very different in the way it executes. Does the other test also refer to the same `service`?

Comment: No, the other test is calling a different service and is using HTTPBuilder instead of RESTClient. Does it look like I configured RESTClient properly?

Comment: I noticed in your sample app you used a class called `co.freeside.betamax.ProxyConfiguration`. I don't see that. Has that been removed in the most recent version of Betamax?

Comment: Weird thing is the exact same code is working fine for a coworker.

Comment: It appears to be an issue when using localhost. When I switched to http://www.google.com/ the tape was written. Shouldn't setting `Recorder recorder = new Recorder(ignoreLocalhost: false)` allow localhost requests to be recorded?